# Add a specific amount to a existing variable VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a homeless millionaire type of game, I have to add a Amount of "Money" to the rest of my "Money" when I press a button+

My Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Money As Decimal = 0
Dim Job As String = 0
Dim PlusMoney As Decimal = 0

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Money = +(PlusMoney)
    Label4.Text = (PlusMoney)
    Label6.Text = (Money)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Job = 0 And Money = 0 Then
        Label5.Text = "McDonalds csicska"
        PlusMoney = 10

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why is "money" a string? I would think this would be a decimal.

Comment: Alt, stop here and go to your project properties. Set Option Strict ON and then try to understand that a STRING is not a NUMBER even when you set it with digit characters.

Comment: Changed it to Decimal

Comment: `Money += PlusMoney`  Lots of beginner issues presented, strongly advise you get started following a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, I just started VB.net!

Comment: If you are just now learning, do yourself a huge favor and turn "Option Strict On", as Steve Suggested earlier.  You can do that from the project properties in the build options.  You may get a few more errors with this turned on, but it will force you to learn to program better.  You will thank yourself years later for learning to do this early before you learn bad habits.

Answer (score 2):

The Main problem with your code is the `Money = +(PlusMoney)` should read `Money += PlusMoney`

`Money = +(PlusMoney)` is equivalent to  `Money = PlusMoney` which does not increment the total by the PlusMoney as intended, instead sets Money to allways be PlusMoney (10) in your case.

`+=` adds the right to the left.

Also Numerical values should have `.ToString()` added to them when assigning them to a string `.Text` Property

```
    Label4.Text = PlusMoney.ToString()
    Label6.Text = Money.ToString()
```